Issue with Rust macro expansion in editor: proc-macro server's api version is newer than rust-analyzer's
After recent update of Rust toolchain version to 1.77.1 (by running rustup update) I've started seeing following error in my editor (Neovim):

Here's the error message in more readable format:
rust-analyzer: proc macro `main` not expanded: Failed to run proc-macro server from path /Users/user/.rustup/toolchains/.../libexec/rust-analyzer-proc-macro-srv, error: Custom { kind: Other, error: "proc-macro server's api version (4) is newer than rust-analyzer's (2)" }

This is annoying as I do not get completions for the symbols that should be generated by macros & seeing a lot of "red" in the editor.
My toolchain is now at latest version 1.77.1, the rust-analyzer version that's being in use here:

is also at version 1.77.1, so in sync with the toolchain.
I've tried inspecting rust-analyzer-proc-macro-srv binary, but all I get is following message:
~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/libexec 
❯ ./rust-analyzer-proc-macro-srv --version
If you're rust-analyzer, you can use this tool by exporting RUST_ANALYZER_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE='this is unstable'.
If not, you probably shouldn't use this tool. But do what you want: I'm an error message, not a cop.

and I clearly do not know my way around these tools...
As I have not found similar issue reported while googling I'm looking for issue explanation &  suggestions of potential solutions, preferably better than downgrading & trying to match toolchain versions with the proc macro srv (maybe how do I update this rust-analyzer-proc-macro-srv or how do I inspect it's version?)

Just checking: have you restarted rust-analyzer and/or Neovim?

You should update rust-analyzer.

@ChayimFriedman: Isn't r-a updated by rustup these days?

@eggyal It depends on how you install it, and use it.

@ChayimFriedman:  Fair.  But OP's rust-analyzer-proc-macro-srv has evidently been updated, so one would presume so too has rust-analyzer (albeit maybe their Neovim is using a different installation.. but then odd that it's using the proc-macro server from this install).

@eggyal I believe (not sure) rust-analyzer always uses the proc macro server of the active Rust installation, not of its own, so it can work with various versions.

Yes, that makes sense it being (as shown in the question) in the toolchain/libexec directory.

The rust-analyzer binary being in use is managed through neovim (mason plugin) and it is at 1.77.1 version (same as the toolchain). I've also installed rust-analyzer via rustup component add rust-analyzer & swapped out this mason managed binary, but it seems it is exactly the same one as the one downloaded with rustup. I'll try downloading rust-analyzer from its release page on GitHub

In your post you say "the rust-analyzer version that's being in use here: ... is also at version 1.77.1", however rust-analyzer is not at version 1 yet and does not track rustc's versions.  The latest rust-analyzer release is v0.3.1906.

That your rust-analyzer is expecting protocol version 2 means that it must be a version prior to v0.3.1766 (which included PR #15959 that bumped to version 3).

@eggyal This is what rust-analyzer reports when querying the version:
❯ rust-analyzer --version
rust-analyzer 1.77.1 (7cf61ebd 2024-03-27)

But you're right, I was surprised yesterday when looking for binary to download on release page and not seeing 1.77....
I've swapped out binary that neovim used for the latest release & the problem was solved! Thanks a lot!

:LspInstall rust_analyzer

This will reinstall the latest version of rust_analyzer for anyone who uses mason in neovim.
Press U to update any additional LSPs when the prompt appears.

The error we experienced is what happens when rust-analyzer and Rustc have drifted enough to become incompatible.
I recently experienced the same symptoms but with Visual Studio Code on MacOS. I updated my Rustc through rustup but could not figure out why so many packages and rust-analyzer could not update appropriately.
For me, it was because Visual Studio Code itself could not update. MacOS has a permissions setting on the 'Downloads' folder for security reasons that was not allowing it to update. By moving it to the appropriate "Applications" folder, Visual Studio Code was able to update so then it could update all its extensions so then I had the right combination of Rustc and rust-analyzer.
In general, if your RustC (rustc -V) is fully up to date and you have this sort of similar issue, look to why you might not have the appropriately up-to-date rust-analyzer.
